# making login.defs active

Tags: password

I am attempting to apply a new password policy on my Ubuntu Server 12.04.1. I have edited the `MAX_PASS_DAYS 30`, `MIN_PASS_DAYS 2`, `PASS_WARN_AGE 7` in `/etc/login.defs`.

The new rules do apply to any new users I create, but how do I force it on all the current users? I test it using a user who has not changed his password in 3 months. `chage -l` still shows `99999` for `MAX_PASS_DAYS`. I would rather not using `chage` on all the current users.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Two years and no answer? Sad to say, the only solution I've come up with is this script. I've tested it on Ubuntu 14. Note that there is no error handling if you give it bad input.

`chage_update.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
usage() { 
    cat <<EOF
Usage: $0 [ YYYY-MM-DD ]

Update chage information for all regular users to the values present in
/etc/login.defs, and set the date of the last password change to YYYY-MM-DD
(defaults to current date). Must be run as root.
EOF
    exit;
}
get_val() {
    ARR=(`grep ^$1 /etc/login.defs`)
    echo ${ARR[1]}
}
UID_MIN=`get_val UID_MIN`
PASS_MAX_DAYS=`get_val PASS_MAX_DAYS`
PASS_WARN_AGE=`get_val PASS_WARN_AGE`
if [ "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    usage
elif [ -z "$1" ]; then
    DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
else
    DATE=$1
fi
cat /etc/passwd | while read line; do
    ARR=($(echo "$line" | cut -d\: -f1-3 | tr : \ ))
    USER=${ARR[0]}
    USERID=${ARR[2]}
    if [ -z "$USERID" ]; then
        continue
    elif [ "$USERID" -ge $UID_MIN ]; then
        chage -d $DATE -M $PASS_MAX_DAYS -W $PASS_WARN_AGE $USER
    fi
done
```

Comment: Embarassing. My get_val() function can be replaced with calls like: `UID_MIN=$(awk '/^UID_MIN/{print $NF}' /etc/login.defs)`